# How can I upload photos from iphone/Android to Drupal?

Tags: 7, theming

I know that I can build iphone/Android apps with frameworks like [phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com) and [titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/).

I wonder if there is an easier way? [Aurigma Up](http://www.aurigma.com/iphone/) seems like an interesting idea. Has anyone used this or similar apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out github, there are some examples of iPhone apps that use services with drupal. this on has allot of functionality, and I know that the creator is quite active in the Drupal community. [https://github.com/workhabitinc/drupal-ios-sdk-example.](https://github.com/workhabitinc/drupal-ios-sdk-example) 
I find objective C realy intimidating and am more familiar with languages like java and js so titanium really great. Here is a great project for titanium
https://github.com/palantirnet/drupalcon_mobile it still has a pretty steap learning curve but much less than learning a new language. If you end up going the titanium rout and you are trying to post images via services, you have to make some alterations to code that compiles titanium (kinda hack it), so that the image blob data can be properly posted. It took me forever to figure this out, if you get that far, let me know and I'll elaborate.

unfortunately, there is really no canned way of facilitating image upload from mobile to drupal, your best bet is to try and use services to post the image through http.

Answer (score 1):

phonegap and titanium are probably considered easier than for example, developing a separate native app for iOS and Android.

However, if you are looking for something even easier, perhaps you could explore using an existing application that uploads images to a service such as Flickr. [A query for iPhone apps on Flickr's App Garden](http://www.flickr.com/services/apps/search/?q=iphone) provides plenty of results. You could then use an app [such as this one](http://www.flickr.com/services/apps/72157622687375343/) to upload images and then use [Flickr's API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/) to create image galleries in Drupal. Plus, you can make calls to Flickr from Drupal and receive data in different formats including JSON and XML. It really doesn't get easier than that.

The [Flickr contrib module](http://drupal.org/project/flickr) could then provide you with plenty of examples of how to query Flickr's API.

The fact that your images would be hosted by a third party could be seen as good or a drawback, depending on how you analyze it.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 6 allows this to be done quite easily. Im working on a few projects myself. Here is my cross answer [Is there any module for picking photos for image field on mobile platforms like iphone](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42743/is-there-any-module-for-picking-photos-for-image-field-on-mobile-platforms-like)

But more feature are found here http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57507927-285/with-ios-6-you-can-upload-photos-in-safari/

Answer (score 0):

[DrupalGap](http://www.drupalgap.org) is an open source mobile application development kit for Drupal websites. It uses PhoneGap and jQueryMobile. Out of the box, DrupalGap offers an image upload feature for your content types.