# Is there any module for picking photos for image field on mobile platforms like iphone

Tags: theming

I think this is probably impossible but I wondered if there was any way to provide image upload or equivalent for mobile platforms for drupal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you'll need to write an iphone application to do the photo upload (using a web service).

There is an [older post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15833/how-can-i-upload-photos-from-iphone-android-to-drupal) with more info.

With Android phones the regular photo upload works, at least that's what I heard from a couple of users.

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 6 they allowed mobile safari to access your photo library and uplode it directly from your phone to the site.

http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/iphone-5-ios-6-html5-developers

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with [DrupalGap](http://www.drupalgap.org).

- [Drupal Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalgap)
- [Mobile Application Development Kit](https://www.github.com/signalpoint/DrupalGap)